# Formula to enumerate all non-empty rows in nearby column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an `=ARRAYFORMULA(...)` for `Column A` for all non-empty rows in `Column B`.

[image]

Does anyone here have any suggestions? Unfortunately, I am a total novice when it comes to excel.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve those numbers/sequential numbers in column A?

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA` is not available in Excel ( it is in Google sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>MAP()</kbd> or <kbd>BYROW()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=MAP(B1:B11,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",COUNTIF(B1:x,"<>"))))
```

---

This one will be more dynamic:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>"")),
     MAP(B1:INDEX(B:B,_lastRow),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",COUNTIF(B1:x,"<>")))))
```

---

The same can be achieved using <kbd>SUBTOTAL()</kbd> or <kbd>COUNTA()</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>"")),
     MAP(B1:INDEX(B:B,_lastRow),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",SUBTOTAL(3,B1:x)))))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(B:B<>"")),
     MAP(B1:INDEX(B:B,_lastRow),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",COUNTA(B1:x)))))
```